# Weird: "connection failure"

Tags: support

A couple of minutes ago, I was experiencing "connection failure"s on Mathematics Stack Exchange, and other sites. What's happening?

Comment: Sometimes, the site is very slow for me too. Could be related...

Comment: @Glorfindel Yeah, it's weird. When you commented, and I tried to see your comment, I got "connection failure" once again.

Comment: I saw that, and interestingly I just got the same error for an article on thehill.com.

Comment: Just saw the same thing on Drones SE.

Comment: I keep seeing that today

Comment: Is it possible that its an excess or overflow of users across all of the SE sites, which makes the server have problems connecting people in a timely fashion?

Comment: uploads of screenshots also seem to be failing. Not sure if its related

Comment: @JourneymanGeek https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11286/178988 - same on ruSO (and screenshot with http headers).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Is it just me or are pages taking longer to load?

Comment: The error shows up when loading new comments too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSW0x.png.

Comment: Its an issue with Fastly by the looks of it: https://status.fastly.com/incidents/1rbr326kjsmt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this issue has been fixed now.